# Radio button whlie pressing back button and back again same activty

Tags: java, android, android-radiobutton

I have a problem , I have an activity in which i am showing  a list view which having user image and radio button of different different user, while I am selecting radio button , it is selected and switch one to another. It is okay but problem is arising while pressing back button and come back same activity.When i am pressing back button and come again same activity on screen its showing default mark on radio button any user, most of time it will come first position. While I am going to mark different profile , it will come with that default marked radio button with recent mark button. I tried to remove by using **adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged()**  then its clear all visibility but while performing action its showing blank radio button but its performing action but not showing which radio button I selected. **Here my code** `

```
public class Suite_Twit_profilelist extends Activity {
    public static Button proceedT;

    RadioButton radioButton2;

    public List<MyComposeObject> connecteds = new ArrayList<MyComposeObject>();
    public MyComposeObject composeObject;

    public ListView listViewT;
    public ProfilelistAdapter1 adapter1;

    String profile_id = null;

    // soap parameters for getting twitter User information
    private static String SOAP_ACTION_OAUTHTOKEN = "******";
    private static String NAMESPACE_OAUTHTOKEN = "******";
    private static String METHOD_NAME_OAUTHTOKEN = "******";
    private static String URL_OAUTHTOKEN = "******";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.suite_twit_profilelist);

        proceedT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwitfl);
        listViewT = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewtwitfl);





        proceedT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (radiobutton_selected1.equals("yes"))
                    new CallToFavourite().execute("");
                else
                    Suite_Login.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                            " Please select some profile ");
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < Suite_Login.composeObjectslist.size(); i++) {
            if (Suite_Login.composeObjectslist.get(i).getCom_profileType()
                    .equals("twitter")) {

                composeObject = new MyComposeObject();
                composeObject
                        .setCom_ProfileName(Woosuite_Login.composeObjectslist
                                .get(i).getCom_ProfileName());
                composeObject
                        .setCom_ProfileImgUrl(Woosuite_Login.composeObjectslist
                                .get(i).getCom_ProfileImgUrl());

                composeObject
                        .setCom_ProfileImgUrl(Suite_Login.composeObjectslist
                                .get(i).getCom_ProfileImgUrl());

                composeObject
                        .setCom_profileId(Woosuite_Login.composeObjectslist
                                .get(i).getCom_profileId());

                connecteds.add(composeObject);
            }



        }

        adapter1 = new ProfilelistAdapter1(Suite_Twit_profilelist.this,
                R.layout.suite_twitte_inflater, connecteds);
        listViewT.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }// end of oncreate

    public class CallToFavourite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println("OAUTHTOKEN " + Singleton.OAUTHTOKEN);
            System.out.println("OAUTHSECRET " + Singleton.OAUTHSECRET);

            System.out.println("FB_CMT_MESSAGE_ID "
                    + Singleton.FB_CMT_MESSAGE_ID);

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory();
            Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();

            // Setting customer key and customer secret key

            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterValues.CONSUMER_KEY,
                    TwitterValues.CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Setting access token,and access Token secret

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(Singleton.OAUTHTOKEN,
                    Singleton.OAUTHSECRET);

            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

            try {
                twitter.createFavorite(Long
                        .parseLong(Singleton.FB_CMT_MESSAGE_ID));
            } catch (TwitterException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Suite_Login.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                    "successfully favourite");
        }
    }

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public static String radiobutton_selected1 = "no";

    public class ProfilelistAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<MyComposeObject> {

        public ImageLoader imageLoader;
        public Context mContext;
        int row;
        public List<MyComposeObject> arrayList;

        // for radio button
        private RadioButton mCurrentlyCheckedRB2;
        private boolean userSelected2 = false;
        private int mResourceId2 = 0;
        private RadioButton mSelectedRB2;
        private int mSelectedPosition2 = -1;




        public ProfilelistAdapter1(Context context, int resource,
                List<MyComposeObject> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            mContext = context;
            row = resource;
            arrayList = objects;

            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        }

        @Override
        public Context getContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mContext;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("arrayList.size() " + arrayList.size());
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("view");
            ViewHolder holder;




            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.username_TextView2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView777);
            holder.radioButton2 = (RadioButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.radio777);
            holder.userimage_ImageView2 = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView777);

            holder.radioButton2.setTag(position);
                if (position == Singleton.selected_schedular) {

                if (radiobutton_selected1.equals("yes"))
                    holder.radioButton2.setChecked(true);
                mCurrentlyCheckedRB2 = holder.radioButton2;
            } else {

                System.out.println("false  ");
                holder.radioButton2.setChecked(false);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            holder.radioButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                    radiobutton_selected1 = "yes";

                    profile_id = arrayList.get(position).getCom_profileId();
                    System.out.println("profile id " + profile_id);

                    System.out.println("profile name "
                            + arrayList.get(position).getCom_ProfileName());

                    new GetOauthToken().execute("");


                    if ((position != mSelectedPosition2 && mSelectedRB2 != null)) {
                    mSelectedRB2.setChecked(false);


                    }

                    mSelectedPosition2 = position;
                    mSelectedRB2 = (RadioButton) v;

                    Singleton.selected = (Integer) v.getTag();

                }
            });

            if (arrayList.get(position).getCom_ProfileName() != null) {

                holder.username_TextView2.setText(arrayList.get(position)
                        .getCom_ProfileName());


                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if (arrayList.get(position).getCom_ProfileImgUrl() != null) {

                imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrayList.get(position)
                        .getCom_ProfileImgUrl(), holder.userimage_ImageView2);


            }
            return convertView;
        }




        private class ViewHolder {

            ImageView userimage_ImageView2;
            TextView username_TextView2;
            CheckBox checkBox2;
            RadioButton radioButton2;
        }
    }

    /*** class for getting twitter oauth secret and oauth token ***/

    public class GetOauthToken extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            Suite_Login.showProgressDialog(Suite_Twit_profilelist.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String result = null;

            System.out.println("background Get twitter oauthToken");

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_OAUTHTOKEN,
                    METHOD_NAME_OAUTHTOKEN);

            // Use this to add parameters
            System.out.println("user_id " + Singleton.user_id);
            request.addProperty("UserId", Singleton.user_id);

            System.out.println("TwitterId " + profile_id);
            request.addProperty("TwitterId", profile_id);

            // Declare the version of the SOAP request
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            try {

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                        URL_OAUTHTOKEN);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

                // this is the actual part that will call the webservice

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_OAUTHTOKEN, envelope);
                SoapObject soap_result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                System.out.println("soap_result  " + soap_result);

                result = soap_result.getProperty(0).toString();

                // System.out.println("result " + result);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                Singleton.OAUTHTOKEN = jsonObject.getString("OAuthToken");

                System.out.println("Singleton.OAUTHTOKEN  "
                        + Singleton.OAUTHTOKEN);

                Singleton.OAUTHSECRET = jsonObject.getString("OAuthSecret");

                System.out.println("Singleton.OAUTHSECRET  "
                        + Singleton.OAUTHSECRET);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }
    }

}
`
```

Comment: You need to preserve the selection somewhere. It can be done using `SharedPreferences` or `Database`

Comment: @GauravGupta Thanks boss.I am not getting . Same thing while a am getting error in different activity and that overcame by using this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Hi guy plz close this . simple answer of this question . I found on backPress , i have change only string radiobutton_selected1 = "No";